# MySQL character ordering: numbers before question mark

Tags: mysql, ascii, collation

I have recently upgraded a MySQL data store from some ungodly many-years-out-of-date version to 8.0.26.

In one particular table I store dates associated with each record, but occasionally there are as-yet-unknown future dates. These have always been stored in the format YYYY-MM-??, so the field type is VARCHAR(10) rather than DATE, as would be expected if it was possible to always be exact. *The field data is otherwise reliably YYYY-MM-DD.*

However, queries to order this data have recently stopped working as expected, with MySQL reckoning that such an unknown date should be ordered BEFORE an exact date.

A query boils down to something like this: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_field <= CURDATE()`

(Today is 3rd December, so `CURDATE` is evaluating as 2021-12-03. The same occurs when using the literal string value 2021-12-03 rather than the `CURDATE` function, so it's definitely a sorting issue rather than clash between data types.)

In those old MySQL versions previously running, 2021-12-?? would evaluate higher/greater than an exact date like 03, and thus not be returned. This would also be expected in line with [ASCII sort ordering](http://support.ecisolutions.com/doc-ddms/help/reportsmenu/ascii_sort_order_chart.htm). Now, however, any such ?? records are also returned, the question mark character apparently being sorted as before/less than a digit.

For the moment I can force the correct and expected behaviour by utilising `REPLACE` in my query, but this is process-heavy, ugly and inconvenient: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE REPLACE(date_field , '??', '99') <= CURDATE()`

Can anyone shed some light on why this is occurring and how I might correct it? It is presumably a MySQL bug, given the standard ASCII ordering and the previous experience (of many years standing) of it working correctly?

---

EDIT: Thanks to the initial replies pointing me to collation. The database uses almost entirely plain English with only occasional accents (etc), so I've rarely had to touch the default settings in the past.

As per ProGu and Álvaro González's responses, I've begun digging around and test queries without the real table/database involved do indeed return as suggested. However, as soon as I attempt to run anything on the real table, it's still not behaving as expected.

The table is on InnoDB, and all tables and (textual) fields across the database are utf8mb4/utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci. I have tried forcing the collation both at query level and by changing the actual table and field collation, yet that pesky `2021-12-??` is always returned, no matter which I choose. I have attempted various query formats to no avail:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_field <= CURDATE() ORDER BY date_field COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DESC`

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_field COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci <= CURDATE() COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ORDER BY date_field COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DESC`

Test based on Álvaro's code, correctly returning `2021-12-03`:

```
with sample_data (sample_value) as (
    select '2021-12-??'
    union all select '2021-12-03'
)
select *
from sample_data
where sample_value <= CURDATE()
order by sample_value COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Is my collation inexperience showing; have I missed something really obvious?

---

**EDIT 2**

All tables and all text columns (plus connection) are already set to `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`.

See [this DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=015dc16565cdc5638423d1fc418c139e), which also incorrectly returns `2021-12-??` as apparently less than the comparison value (current date, `2021-12-08`). I can find no collation that returns the real smaller value (`2021-10-31` in the sample data).

Going back to Rick's initial reply:
`SELECT "2021-12-??" < "2021-12-03"`

This returns 1, i.e. that `03` IS *greater than* `??`. Why? ASCII ordering is clear that digit characters come before - *less than* - the question mark character.

As in the original version of my post, it seems to me that MySQL is getting character ordering wrong when it is using digits as string rather than int.

Compare:

`SELECT "?" < "0";` = 1

`SELECT "?" < 0;` = 0

Comment: it's charset problem, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=84220ec1f389f370ebd0defdd945a4f9

Comment: @ProGu That is 99+% likely the answer. Write it up.

Comment: Did you mean YYYY instead of YYY?

Comment: I certainly did! Thanks Rick.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not fully sure of what your latest snippet is trying to illustrate. But there's certainly an additional issue related to `curdate()`. I've edited my answer to add information about that.

Comment: Why can't you set the `-??` dates to null?

Comment: @SalmanA This is desired and required data to keep track of events for which a month has been set, but the exact day not confirmed.

Comment: It is definitely a collation issue. Please post the result of `show create table`. I suspect that you did not explicitly specify collation when creating the tables. In which case it defaulted to utf8mb4_general_ci in mysql5 and utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci in mysql8. The `?` sorts after and before digits in these collations respectively. And no, it is the collation rules, not ascii code that determines the result of comparison.

Comment: ```CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_field` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=69107 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;```

As you can see, everything explicitly set.

Answer (score 1):

This is a collation issue. You're probably relying on the default collation and that has changed.

You can change the collation at query level to figure out which ones suits your need and then adjust the table or column collation accordingly:

```
with sample_data (sample_value) as (
    select '?'
    union all select '0'
)
select *
from sample_data
order by sample_value COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

| Result |
| --- |
| 0 |
| ? |

```
with sample_data (sample_value) as (
    select '?'
    union all select '0'
)
select *
from sample_data
order by sample_value COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_cs;
```

| Result |
| --- |
| ? |
| 0 |

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=13effdac42b080609e76960729d28725)

Please note I mean collation and not encoding. You should be able to keep your current encoding if it isn't UTF-8.

---

**Edit #1:** these snippets are only a tool to decide which collation to choose. The fix to the problem is not to add a random `ORDER BY` clause at the end of your query, the fix is to change the table (or column) collation:

[image: MySQL Workbench - Alter table]

**Edit #2:**

`where sample_value <= CURDATE()` seemingly ignores table collation, but that's probably due to automatic casting from date type. If you force a cast to text things change:

```
where sample_value <= cast(curdate() as char(10))
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0326b296f5c2891bcde69187625232f5)

My advice is that you first set a good known default collation everywhere (tables, connection...). It's possible that that will fix all issues.

Comment: Thank you, Álvaro! That certainly seems to be on the right track. I can't quite figure out the correct collation though - I have updated my original post above.

Comment: `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` [works fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=005cea99ef859ddb9b38a4c89bbe4e68) but your latest snippet doesn't illustrate that (`sample_value <= CURDATE()` still uses the default table collation). I'm using `order by` as a way to verify a given collation renders the expected order, I wasn't implying the fix to the problem is to add an `order by` clause! You need to open your favourite MySQL client and edit the table collation to set it to `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`.

Comment: Thanks for the further attention, Álvaro, but you've missed my point: utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci *already is* the default collation on both the table and the column. I will attempt to create a better working example of my issue in DB Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to change the code a little.  It is unclear which of the cases below apply to your code.

```
mysql> SELECT "2021-12-??" < "2021-12-03";
+-----------------------------+
| "2021-12-??" < "2021-12-03" |
+-----------------------------+
|                           1 |
+-----------------------------+

mysql> SELECT "2021-12-??" < CURDATE();
ERROR 1525 (HY000): Incorrect DATE value: '2021-12-??'

mysql> SELECT "2021-12-??" < CAST(CURDATE() AS CHAR);
+----------------------------------------+
| "2021-12-??" < CAST(CURDATE() AS CHAR) |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                      1 |
+----------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT DATE(NOW()) <= CAST(CURDATE() AS CHAR);
+----------------------------------------+
| DATE(NOW()) <= CAST(CURDATE() AS CHAR) |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                      1 |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Rick. A good spot, but already catered for in my real, live code with `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')`. Omitted in the post examples to attempt clarity, but perhaps it needs mentioning!

Comment: @Aaron - `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')` gives the same result as `CURDATE()`.  However, it may have different datatype or collation issues.  I think `DATE_FORMAT` produces a `VARCHAR`, which can have collation issues.  Meanwhile, `CHARDATE` gives a `DATE` datatype, which led to the hiccup in my 2nd example.  Play around the various options; see which one works for you.